# Normalization with apply

Tags: r

I'm working on a project for a colleague to normalize GC data and convert from mol% to mass%.

Edit: I'm doing row-wise normalization. i.e. at each time the sum of the species in `norm1` should be 100 (though each is multiplied by mass and so no longer sums to 100. In a for loop it would be equivalent to a very burdensome:

```
for (time in Nmass[,1]){
   for species in norm1{
      Nmass[time,species] = Fmolwt[species,] = Nmass[time,species] / rowSums(Nmass[time,norm1])
                       }
                       }
```

I have the CSV files imported and they are arranged as columns of species names and rows of injection times (working on dummy data so all zeros currently).

```
> Nmass[1:5,c("Time",norm1)]
# A tibble: 5 x 13
  Time                HTFeed_Methane HTFeed_Ethane HTFeed_Ethylene HTFeed_Propane HTFeed_Propylene `HTFeed_iso-butane` `HTFee~ `HTFeed~ `HTFe~ HTFee~ `HTFee~ `HTFee~
  <dttm>                       <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>               <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2019-10-06 13:02:00              0             0               0              0                0                   0       0        0      0      0       0       0
2 2019-10-06 13:17:00              0             0               0              0                0                   0       0        0      0      0       0       0
3 2019-10-06 13:32:00              0             0               0              0                0                   0       0        0      0      0       0       0
4 2019-10-06 13:47:00              0             0               0              0                0                   0       0        0      0      0       0       0
5 2019-10-06 14:02:00              0             0               0              0                0                   0       0        0      0      0       0       0
```

I have a working normalization routine:

```
norm1 = c('HTFeed_Methane','HTFeed_Ethane','HTFeed_Ethylene','HTFeed_Propane','HTFeed_Propylene','HTFeed_iso-butane','HTFeed_n-Butane',
        'HTFeed_trans-2-butene','HTFeed_1-Butene','HTFeed_Isobutylene','HTFeed_cis-2-butene','HTFeed_1,3-Butadiene')

Nmass[,norm1] = as.data.frame(apply(Nmass[,norm1], 2, function(x) x/sum(x)))
```

But when I attempt to implement the mass conversion using a prebuilt list of masses by species:

```
Fmolwt = data.frame(c(16.04,30.07,28.05,44.9,42.08,58.12,58.12,56.11,56.11,56.11,56.11,54.1))
colnames(Fmolwt)[1] = 'weight'
rownames(Fmolwt) = c('HTFeed_Methane','HTFeed_Ethane','HTFeed_Ethylene','HTFeed_Propane','HTFeed_Propylene','HTFeed_iso-butane',
                    'HTFeed_n-Butane','HTFeed_trans-2-butene','HTFeed_1-Butene','HTFeed_Isobutylene','HTFeed_cis-2-butene','HTFeed_1,3-Butadiene')
```

The routine becomes (I think):

```
Nmass[,norm1] = as.data.frame(apply(Nmass[,norm1], 2, function(x) x*Fmolwt[x,]/sum(x)))
```

I get an error about sizes being different.

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 3696
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In x * Fmolwt[x, ] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In x * Fmolwt[x, ] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In x * Fmolwt[x, ] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In x * Fmolwt[x, ] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
5: In x * Fmolwt[x, ] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
6: In x * Fmolwt[x, ] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
7: In x * Fmolwt[x, ] :
```

I expect this is due to the apply statement attempting pull in the molecular weights of everything named in `norm1` at the same time.

Can I do this work the way I'm trying or do I need to write out a for loop?

Comment: Don't use `apply` to loop over data.frame columns. Use `lapply`. Anyway, if you want to iterate over two vectors/lists/data.frames simultaneously, you can use `mapply`.

Comment: @Roland any chance you could point me in the right direction for mapply in this case?

Comment: Hi @BenA, i looked through your explanation and corrected the answer. Hope it's correct this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug here:

```
Nmass[,norm1] = as.data.frame(apply(Nmass[,norm1], 2, function(x) x*Fmolwt[x,]/sum(x)))
```

With apply(..,2,..), you are calling out the column entries with x, and from what I gather, you need to do row-wise operations. Secondly, Fmolwt[x,] gives an error because you are calling out values (not colnames) that match the rownames of Fmolwt.

I simulate some data that looks like yours below, for illustration:

```
set.seed(1234)

norm1 = c('HTFeed_Methane','HTFeed_Ethane','HTFeed_Ethylene',
'HTFeed_Propane','HTFeed_Propylene','HTFeed_iso-butane',
'HTFeed_n-Butane','HTFeed_trans-2-butene',
'HTFeed_1-Butene','HTFeed_Isobutylene','HTFeed_cis-2-butene',
'HTFeed_1,3-Butadiene')

values <- matrix(abs(rnorm(120,1000,100)),ncol=12)
colnames(values) = norm1

ts <- seq(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01", tz = "UTC"),
    as.POSIXct("2017-01-02", tz = "UTC"),
    length.out = 100)

Nmass = data.frame(Time=ts,values,check.names=F)

Fmolwt = data.frame(c(16.04,30.07,28.05,44.9,42.08,58.12,58.12,
56.11,56.11,56.11,56.11,54.1))
colnames(Fmolwt)[1] = 'weight'
rownames(Fmolwt) = c('HTFeed_Methane','HTFeed_Ethane','HTFeed_Ethylene',
'HTFeed_Propane','HTFeed_Propylene',
'HTFeed_iso-butane','HTFeed_n-Butane','HTFeed_trans-2-butene',
'HTFeed_1-Butene','HTFeed_Isobutylene','HTFeed_cis-2-butene',
'HTFeed_1,3-Butadiene')
```

How the simulated data looks like:

```
> head(Nmass,2)
                 Time HTFeed_Methane HTFeed_Ethane HTFeed_Ethylene
1 2017-01-01 00:00:00       879.2934      952.2807       1013.4088
2 2017-01-01 00:14:32      1027.7429      900.1614        950.9314
  HTFeed_Propane HTFeed_Propylene HTFeed_iso-butane HTFeed_n-Butane
1      1110.2298        1144.9496          819.3969        1065.659
2       952.4407         893.1357          941.7924        1254.899
  HTFeed_trans-2-butene HTFeed_1-Butene HTFeed_Isobutylene HTFeed_cis-2-butene
1             1000.6893        982.2210           994.6841           1041.4524
2              954.4531        983.0006          1025.5196            952.5282
  HTFeed_1,3-Butadiene
1             980.4065
2             935.0930
```

First step, we take first row as example, to normalize it (by its total) and then multiply by the corresponding mass, for example row 1, do:

```
Fmolwt[norm1,]*Nmass[1,norm1]/sum(Nmass[1,norm1])
```

Gives you the following results:

```
  HTFeed_Methane HTFeed_Ethane HTFeed_Ethylene HTFeed_Propane HTFeed_Propylene
1       1.176825      2.389309        2.371873       4.159423         4.020092
  HTFeed_iso-butane HTFeed_n-Butane HTFeed_trans-2-butene HTFeed_1-Butene
1          3.973688        5.167942              4.685041        4.598576
  HTFeed_Isobutylene HTFeed_cis-2-butene HTFeed_1,3-Butadiene
1           4.656926            4.875886             4.425653
```

If you want to use the in-built r function, the easiest is apply, which you have used:

```
results = t(apply(Nmass[,norm1],1,function(x){
      Fmolwt[norm1,]*x/sum(x)
    }))
```

So following what we have before, x is a row from Nmass[,norm1], so we do x/sum(x) to normalize, then multiply by Fmolwt[norm1,]. The values match because we started with Nmass[,norm1]. Now we need to transpose the results to get the same dimensions as Nmass, hence the t(apply(..)).

If we look at the first row, it gives the same output as the example above:

```
> results[1,]
       HTFeed_Methane         HTFeed_Ethane       HTFeed_Ethylene 
             1.176825              2.389309              2.371873 
       HTFeed_Propane      HTFeed_Propylene     HTFeed_iso-butane 
             4.159423              4.020092              3.973688 
      HTFeed_n-Butane HTFeed_trans-2-butene       HTFeed_1-Butene 
             5.167942              4.685041              4.598576 
   HTFeed_Isobutylene   HTFeed_cis-2-butene  HTFeed_1,3-Butadiene 
             4.656926              4.875886              4.425653
```

So if you want to put the results back, do

```
Nmass[,norm] = results
```

Comment: I'm actually normalizing by row, I need the GC values at the same time stamp normalized. So the 2 makes it work correctly there, right? But I see that it breaks the mass multiplication.

Comment: Ok if I get you correct, for every row, you want to multiply by the matching mass value and divide by the sum of the row? I have edited my answer

Comment: In the tmp when you call out ```Fmolwt*Nmass[,norm1]``` does it know magically to multiply the matching Fmolwt entry for the norm1 entry?   If I have Methane/(Methane+Ethane) as a simple case I need the mass version to be the equivalent of Fmolwt$methane * Methane/(Methane+Ethane)

Comment: I updated my edit in the OP to show how I would for loop through the structure. I don't want the burden of a for loop and I'd like to leverage the built in features in R to make it better. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ben for editing the post, yes it's clearer. Sorry I was a bit confused about what is what. I have edited my post now, it should give you what you want. In the future, to prevent confusion, it's better to put some example data , like dput(head(Nmass,5)) , and show the expected results

Comment: That is a perfect and great explanation! Thank you so much for your help, it makes much better sense now. (and works too!)

Comment: Great @BenA! Glad it helped :)